# ROW_NUMBER Skip Rows Based on Condition

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have a calendar table that has a key (integer) column on every date. Valid business dates are assigned keys; they go in ascending order.  Problem is, Saturdays and Sundays are not considered valid business dates, so they have a value of "9999."  What I want to do in this case is use the row that comes after the "9999" as the "Next" value instead of using the row with the "9999."  So, to explain in pseudo code, I'm looking for something like:

```
Case When nex.KEY = '9999' Then skip it and find the nex.KEY row that is not '9999'
    Else CTE.NEXT_DT
END AS Next
```

I started with a CTE, but am open to ideas.  Here is an output sample of what I am able to get now.  The '9999' values in column "Next" are what I'm looking to update.

Current Output:

```
rowNum  DAY BUSINESS_DT KEY     PREV_DT     NEXT_DT     Previous Next
3932    Sun 2015-09-13  9999    2015-09-11  2015-09-14  9999    2709
3933    Mon 2015-09-14  2709    2015-09-11  2015-09-15  9999    2710
3934    Tue 2015-09-15  2710    2015-09-14  2015-09-16  2709    2711
3935    Wed 2015-09-16  2711    2015-09-15  2015-09-17  2710    2712
3936    Thu 2015-09-17  2712    2015-09-16  2015-09-18  2711    2713
3937    Fri 2015-09-18  2713    2015-09-17  2015-09-21  2712    9999
3938    Sat 2015-09-19  9999    2015-09-18  2015-09-21  2713    9999
3939    Sun 2015-09-20  9999    2015-09-18  2015-09-21  9999    2714
3940    Mon 2015-09-21  2714    2015-09-18  2015-09-22  9999    2715
```

Desired Output:

```
rowNum  DAY BUSINESS_DT KEY     PREV_DT     NEXT_DT     Previous Next
3932    Sun 2015-09-13  9999    2015-09-11  2015-09-14  9999    2709
3933    Mon 2015-09-14  2709    2015-09-11  2015-09-15  9999    2710
3934    Tue 2015-09-15  2710    2015-09-14  2015-09-16  2709    2711
3935    Wed 2015-09-16  2711    2015-09-15  2015-09-17  2710    2712
3936    Thu 2015-09-17  2712    2015-09-16  2015-09-18  2711    2713
3937    Fri 2015-09-18  2713    2015-09-17  2015-09-21  2712    **2714**
3938    Sat 2015-09-19  9999    2015-09-18  2015-09-21  2713    **2714**
3939    Sun 2015-09-20  9999    2015-09-18  2015-09-21  9999    2714
3940    Mon 2015-09-21  2714    2015-09-18  2015-09-22  9999    2715
```

Below is my code:

```
WITH CTE AS
(
Select 
rowNum = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY d.CALENDAR_DT_ID),
d.DAY,
d.KEY,
d.BUSINESS_DT,
d.PREV_DT,
d.NEXT_DT,
d.HOLIDAY_IN
FROM CALENDAR_DT d
)

SELECT
CTE.rowNum,
CTE.DAY,
CTE.BUSINESS_DT,
CTE.KEY,
CTE.PREV_DT,
CTE.NEXT_DT,
prev.KEY As Previous,
nex.KEY As Next

FROM CTE
LEFT JOIN CTE prev ON prev.rownum = CTE.rownum - 1 
LEFT JOIN CTE nex ON nex.rownum = CTE.rownum + 1
ORDER BY BUSINESS_DT
```

Comment: You have shown what you could achieve so far. Can you also show what your are desiring to get as output?

Comment: Is KEY always a serial number except for 9999 key rows?

Comment: Yes.  A unique number for each, in ascending order.  The calendar table started in 2004, so we are now up to 2709 for 9/13, 2710 for 9/14, and so on.  For all non-holidays and non-weekends, each day key increments by one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**SQL Fiddle Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b807e/1)

```
;WITH CTE1 AS
(
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY CALENDAR_DT_ID) AS RN1,
    DAY1,
    BUSINESS_DT,
    KEY1
    FROM DATESCHART
)
,CTE2 AS
(
    SELECT 1 AS SNO,1 AS RN2,* FROM CTE1 WHERE RN1=1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT CASE WHEN C1.KEY1=9999 THEN C2.SNO ELSE C2.SNO+1 END,RN2+1,c1.* 
    FROM CTE1 C1 INNER JOIN CTE2 C2 ON C1.RN1 = C2.RN2
)

SELECT C1.DAY1,C1.BUSINESS_DT,C1.KEY1,C3.BUSINESS_DT PREV_DT,C2.BUSINESS_DT NEXT_DT,C3.KEY1 PREVIOUS,C2.KEY1 NEXTK 
FROM CTE2 C1 LEFT JOIN CTE2 C2 ON C1.SNO+1 = C2.SNO AND C2.KEY1<>9999 
             LEFT JOIN CTE2 C3 ON C1.SNO-1 = C3.SNO AND C3.KEY1<>9999 
WHERE C1.RN2>1
```

Comment: plus one for the fiddle.  works perfectly.  thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I think you can just change the join conditions to `nex` and `prev` to use the dates instead of using the row numbers.

```
WITH CTE AS
(
Select 
    rowNum = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY d.CALENDAR_DT_ID),
    d.DAY,
    d.KEY,
    d.BUSINESS_DT,
    d.PREV_DT,
    d.NEXT_DT,
    d.HOLIDAY_IN
FROM CALENDAR_DT d
)
SELECT
    CTE.rowNum,
    CTE.DAY,
    CTE.BUSINESS_DT,
    CTE.KEY,
    CTE.PREV_DT,
    CTE.NEXT_DT,
    prev.KEY As Previous,
    nex.KEY As Next
FROM CTE
LEFT JOIN CTE prev 
ON CTE.PREV_DT = prev.BUSINESS_DT
LEFT JOIN CTE nex 
ON CTE.NEXT_DT = nex.BUSINESS_DT
ORDER BY BUSINESS_DT
```

Comment: Did you try this? It is less complicated and will perform better. Your data shows that your next and previous dates already point to the business date key you need.